# How to unblock the Developer tools

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access the developer tools on this domain "http://umang.gov.in" using F12 or right click of the mouse but the site website developer block this option.
I follow this step to access this.
Open browser menu > More tools > Developer Tools.
But it is too long process please help me provide me the alternative of it.

Comment: Just select the address bar (or something not in the site tab proper) and then you can press F12 or control-shift-i or whatever you need, probably

Comment: For mac cmd+control+I would do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

**If you just want to inspect the elements and see then you can follow this:**
Open an empty tab and press F12 and then copy and paste this Url in the address bar : http://umang.gov.in

Answer (score 1):

brave browser after clicking the top right corner menu:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the console using right click in a new tab. Then simply copy and paste the URL in that tab. You will get the DOM there.